# Excel Counting error

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I am trying to sum the lead count data having the condition that it should be >0 and the gender should be MALE. I don't want to use `countifs` because it is not supported by excelcius.

I have tried the following formula:

```
=IF('Universe data'!R2:R801>0,IF('Universe data'!H2:H801=MALE,COUNT('Universe data'!R2:R801)))
```

it gives me an #N/A error.

How can this be accomplished using COUNTIF?

Here is the data: 
The op i want is the sum of the males whose lead count is not 0 the answer should be 10 and how do i count the no of male and female the countif is giving either all the rows or eithr 0

```
gender    lead count      
--------  -----------
MALE            0
MALE            6
FEMALE          1
FEMALE          2
MALE            1
FEMALE          1
MALE            3
FEMALE          1
MALE            0
MALE            0
```

Thanks & regards

Comment: Please show us some data and tell us the values you expect to see from your formula. Also, do you want to use COUNTIF or not?

Comment: Does Excelcius support `SumProduct`? If so, you could use the formula `=SumProduct(--(('Universe data'!R2:R801>0), --('Universe data'!H2:H801="MALE"))` to replace the countif

Answer (score 4):

I got a working solution to this. But it works only because the value you do not want to count is 0.

use `=SUMIF(A:A;"MALE";B:B)`

This is how it looks in my example:
[image]

**Edit:** If you want to count male with a value above 0, and add 1 for each regardless of their value. Add another column And write this if statement in the column: `=IF(B2<>0;1;0)`

Then use this formula: `=SUMIF(A:A;"MALE";C:C)`
[image]

Hope this is what you wanted. If not give me some feedback and ill try to adopt it. :)

Comment: Hi ole and whatif i want to count the number of Male and female not equal to zero my count if is not working its giving all the count or either 0

Comment: The problem with count if is that it also counts 0. The only real solution to this is to ether ad another column or to use `countifs`. If it is possible for you to ad a column with a formula i can show you how to calculate it with `countif`.

Comment: ya show me no problem previously i did it with countifs but the software with which excel is integrated doesnot support countifs and sum ifs and suppose if there is another column say age group with values like 21-30,31-45,45+ u can assign any age group to the ablove excel then how do i sum them depending on the age group its getting complicated

Comment: This question is evolving, hehe ;) You can just change the variable if the different IF statements. Instead of "MALE" use "21-30". Btw. do you work in a media agency? :)

Comment: hehe i am just a trainee accts just got into excel i thought it will be a piece of cake with countifs yaa and for the solution i want the age group,gender as well as the lead thats just the tip of the iceberg i am trying every thing ones ran outs of If,s hehe :)

Comment: Cool, a good tip is to watch a few courses at Lynda.com. After taking 1 or two excel courses on Lynda.com you are well suited to solve most problems that don't require macros. Regarding the problem with age groups try to set up all variables you want in different columns, and then think about what intermediary columns you need to calculate them and sum them up the right way. :)

Comment: Also, if my answer solved you problem, remember to mark the question as answered. :) And if you work with marketing please support the new Marketing Q&A on area 51. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51786/marketing .